# RegEx to match any character except strings with surrounding prefixes

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to create a regex which will validate input to match any character but it should exclude input which is surrounded with prefixes (i.e. {#..#}, {@..@} or {$..$}).

Given is the example:

```
Free text which is fine // should return true
{#some other text#} // should return false
Text with numbers 671 // should return true
{@Hello world@} // should return false
{$Hello Mars$} // should return false
{$some text which i do not close // should return true
```

This should be possible with the use of negative look-around, something along the lines of:

```
^(\?!=(\{@[^.]+@\}))(\?!=(\{$[^.]+$\}))(\?!=(\{#[^.]+#\})).*
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated : )

Comment: what about `{# what is that text? $}` is that enclosed or a free text?

Comment: this is free text, i'm only looking for text that is enclosed with {#..#}, {@..@} or {$..$}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You syntax is a bit weird if you ask me... I would suggest:

```
^(?!\{(?:[$@#]).*(?:[$@#])\}).*
```

[Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/wY9nQ0)

First 'group' is `\{(?:[$@#])` which looks for the opening prefix, then `.*` to match everything in the middle and `(?:[$@#])\}` to match the closing suffix.

Note that it will not allow things like:

```
{$Hello Mars$} how are you?
```

If you want it to accept this as well, add an end of line anchor:

```
^(?!\{(?:[$@#]).*(?:[$@#])\}$).*
                            ^
```

[Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/gU0fA8)

You can use the character class to have the different symbols `[@$#]` and is shorter than having multiple negative lookarounds or `|` operators in side :)

EDIT: To prevent things like `{#Free text which is fine$}'` you could use:

```
^(?!\{([$@#]).*\1\}).*
```

Or

```
^(?!\{([$@#]).*\1\}$).*
```

For the second version.

`\1` is a backreference and refers to the first captured group (any of `$`, `@`, or `#`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation, it all makes sense now; not to use multiple negative lookarounds or the | operator, this is far simpler in usage!

Comment: Almost but **not correct** Though, '{#Free text which is fine$}' whill be considered as Sorounded Text...

Comment: @TomerW Good point. I edited my answer to provide for this case.

Comment: Now it is Complete and Amazing :)